# Differences between inet_aton() and gethostbyname() in C?

Tags: c, gethostbyname, inet, inet-aton

I'm studying C and TCP/UDP. 
As the title... Is there any difference between inet_aton() and gethostbyname() in C? From what I know, both convert an IP address from a string to a number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**gethostbyname**() is obsolete. You should use **getaddrinfo()**.

**inet_aton**() only works for IPv4.

Also, **inet_aton**() only convert a IPv4 notion (0.0.0.0) to int, **getaddrinfo** does DNS resolution.

Comment: Plus there's the fact that `getaddrinfo` (and the old `gethostbyname`) can also look up hostnames via DNS, while `inet_aton` only works with IP addresses in string form.

Answer (score 2):

**gethostbyname()** is used for getting ip-address from hostname and store them in struct in_addr.Where as **inet_aton** takes in the ip address in dotted format and converts into network byte order .